# DialogueAsync API is failed to open Google Oauth url

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

I am trying to connect Google Oauth using DialogueAsync API in native outlook client.

```
Outlook client version details :
Version : 16.13(180513)
Mac OS
```

When I open the URL with AsyncAPI, it is throwing an error. If i do same with child window, it is successfully opening.

Child window approach is invoking popup blocker in Windows Outlook client. so it is failing to go through app submission.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test App</title>
</head>


<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3qov000jfn2nk.cloudfront.net/webaddin/js/core-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3qov000jfn2nk.cloudfront.net/office-bf.js"></script>

    <script>

        function dialogueOauth() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Opened dialogue API OAuth window";
            Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&display=popup&prompt=consent&include_granted_scopes=true&client_id=68597033215-jbnt69ru2e2k23mja1a5oumjrtvhon77.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://sf.xenovusapps.net/auth/google/callback&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
        }

        function childWindowOauth() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Opened child window OAuth";
            window.open("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&display=popup&prompt=consent&include_granted_scopes=true&client_id=68597033215-jbnt69ru2e2k23mja1a5oumjrtvhon77.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://sf.xenovusapps.net/auth/google/callback&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
        }

    </script>

    <button onclick="dialogueOauth()">connect oAuth with DialogueAPI</button>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <button onclick="childWindowOauth()">connect oAuth with ChildWindow</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Below is an example app:
HTML file : https://d3qov000jfn2nk.cloudfront.net/test-oauth-stackoverflow/oauth-test.html

Manifest file : 
https://d3qov000jfn2nk.cloudfront.net/test-oauth-stackoverflow/test-app.xml

**Error:**
[image]

Comment: displayDialogAsync  is the recommended approach for opening auth windows from addins. To clarify, is displayDialogAsync working for you in Windows Outlook? Could you give more details on the error you get from Mac Outlook client?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT added error screenshot. you can install the manifest and reproduce the error

Comment: I installed your manifest, but it just shows the default google home page. (probably not intended) I don't reproduce your error. However, I looked at the code you have above, and your call has a "space" in it. Which I don't think is allowed, can you adjust your URL so there isn't a space? When I just go to your url with the space removed, I show the error you have. Can you just replace with %20?

Comment: We are still unable to reproduce this issue. We are able to successfully use displayDialogAsync to load up the Google Auth page without seeing the error from your screenshot. That error usually means that the url for the page contains "&action=" and that is probably not allowed. We don't see the "&action=" parameter in the HTML file of your example app. Are you still experiencing this issue?